# Get GridView Row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView which I bind to a SqlDataReader on Page_Load. It has a column with buttons and I am trying to get the row when a button is clicked with the following code:

```
int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];
```

**EDIT** : Pasting the .aspx page from the comments sectio

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" DataKeyNames="id" GridLines="None"> <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" /> 
    <Columns> 
        <asp:TemplateField> 
             <ItemTemplate> 
                  <asp:Button ID="btnChange" runat="server" Text="Change" CommandName="Test" Visible='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Tested")) == true ? true : false %>' /> 
             </ItemTemplate> 
         </asp:TemplateField> 
     </Columns>
</aspx:GridView>
```

I get the following error:  'System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.' on line 'int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);'.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint on int index=.. and checked what e.CommandArgument is? Its most likely a value that cannot be converted to an integer.

Comment: Did you bother to examine the value of e.CommandArgument?  The documentation says that a `FormatException` will be thrown when 'value does not consist of an optional sign followed by a sequence of digits (0 through 9).'  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b.aspx

Comment: Are you doing this on OnRowCommand?

Comment: i examine the commandArgument and is "". But why does this happens ?. @Emaad Ali Yes i am doing this on GridView1_RowCommand

Comment: Can you post the .aspx page where you have set the command argument?

Comment: The key appears to be that there is no value ("") for the Button.CommandArgument.  Post your ASPX markup plus your full code for the RowCommand event.  It would seem we need to figure out why CommandArgument is not being set.

Comment: @Vinay     <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" DataKeyNames="id"
        GridLines="None">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />

        <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
      <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Button ID="btnChange" runat="server" Text="Change" CommandName="Test" 
              Visible='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Tested")) == true ? true : false %>' />
      </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to check which command in the GridView row has been clicked. Your markup should correspondingly map. See egs below.
The e.CommandArgument you are getting may not correspond to your button click.

In CodeBehind:

```
    void GridView1_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
    // If multiple buttons are used in a GridView control, use the CommandName property to determine which button was clicked.
    if(e.CommandName=="Add")
    {
    // Convert the row index stored in the CommandArgument property to an Integer.
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

    // Retrieve the row that contains the button clicked by the user from the Rows collection.
    GridViewRow row = CustomersGridView.Rows[index];

    // additional logic...
    }
    // additional logic...
}
```

In Markup:

Also please ensure you have set your CommandArgument attribute appropriately. Example below:

```
<asp:Button (...) CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>" />
```

OR use a buttonfield

```
<asp:ButtonField ButtonType="button" CommandName="Add" Text="Add" />
```

Comment: The ButtonField will automatically populate the CommandArgument with the index of the row; using a regular Button OP will need to explicitly set the CommandArgument.  Just clarifying the difference; your approaches are correct.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I was in the process of editing the answer with your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Can u  post the whole markup code,it would be helpful to solve. according to your question
in gridview aspx code you have  to use Command Name, and command Argument for the Button Control and it should bind to the one of the column of db. and use Row Command event of gridview. And also Try to use ItemTemplate to put Control Inside the gridview.

Click here for MSDN Documentation. [Row Command in GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx)

```
protected void Grid_RowCommand( object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e )
{
    int index = Convert.ToInt32( e.CommandArgument );
    your logic .......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not added value to the command Argument. For your Button event in .aspx page

```
<asp:Button ID="btnChange" runat="server" Text="Change" CommandName="Test" CommandArgument = 1 Visible='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Tested")) == true ? true : false %>' />
```

In the code behind i.e the RowCommand Event

```
if(e.CommandName == "Test")
{
int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
}
```

This will work only for value 1. To make it generic you can bind the command Argument to the value you want using one of the binding techniques for example : `CommandArgument ='<%# Eval("ID") %>'` (Assuming ID is present in the GridView)

Comment: The first way will only work for the second row (CommandArgument = "1").  Your second approach (Binding on "ID") may not work because your making the (dangerous) assumption that the ID field will match the row index.

Comment: The first one was just an example to show that you need to specify a command argument in the .aspx page. The second approach was to just let them know that they can bind the events too. I do understand that it only binds with a column ID from the gridview.

Comment: The OP (or someone with the same question who looks at this later) may not realize that it was an example to show how it is done.  I would recommend editing your answer to make it more clear - just because you (or I) know what you *meant* doesn't mean a less experienced or brand new developer will.

Comment: Yeah I understand. I just edited the answer. Let me know if this clears the confusion. :)

Answer (score -1):

Check out this code

```
void ContactsGridView_RowCommand(Object sender,GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
// If multiple buttons are used in a GridView control, use the
// CommandName property to determine which button was clicked.
if(e.CommandName=="Add")
{
  // Convert the row index stored in the CommandArgument
  // property to an Integer.
  int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

  // Retrieve the row that contains the button clicked 
  // by the user from the Rows collection.
  GridViewRow row = ContactsGridView.Rows[index];

  // Create a new ListItem object for the contact in the row.     
  ListItem item = new ListItem();
  item.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells[2].Text) + " " +
    Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells[3].Text);

  // If the contact is not already in the ListBox, add the ListItem 
  // object to the Items collection of the ListBox control. 
  if (!ContactsListBox.Items.Contains(item))
  {
    ContactsListBox.Items.Add(item);
  }
 }
}
```

Below html code for gridview

```
<asp:gridview id="ContactsGridView" 
          datasourceid="ContactsSource"
          allowpaging="true" 
          autogeneratecolumns="false"
          onrowcommand="ContactsGridView_RowCommand"
          runat="server">

          <columns>
            <asp:buttonfield buttontype="Link" 
              commandname="Add" 
              text="Add"/>
            <asp:boundfield datafield="ContactID" 
              headertext="Contact ID"/>
            <asp:boundfield datafield="FirstName" 
              headertext="First Name"/> 
            <asp:boundfield datafield="LastName" 
              headertext="Last Name"/>
          </columns>

        </asp:gridview>
```

Check link [Gridview commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx)

Hope this answer helps you.

Comment: but the error is on int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

Comment: @nevayeshirazi very funny buddy

Comment: Ok so when you click on button what command name come in e.commandName??

Comment: if (e.CommandName == "Test")
                int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                GridViewRow row = ((GridView)e.CommandSource).Rows[index];. It has the correct command because it goes inside the If statement

Comment: @Emaad Ali, you could have corrected your answer instead of spamming   -1 to my posts. I was trying to be constructive. Your answer needs better explanation instead of just copying and pasting from somewhere else. Sorry reported.

Comment: @nevayeshirazi, listen buddy its my own answer i am here to help this user as fast as i can so please do your work and let me to do my work to help this user,thanks.

Comment: @Pikk: what sort of button you are using?mean link button etc?

Comment: You can see the .aspx source that i posted above for Vinay

Comment: check links i mentioned in answer.

Comment: Hi pikk, kindly check my answer now, hope you can understand it clearly well now and vote me up.